# How to remove the particular scss if the component get destroyed?

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

I am using PrimeNG for my project I used p-dropdown with appendTo body only for particular components files, and I changed the css in only one file as follow, for example

`geneFinder.component.scss`

```
.ui-dropdown-panel {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

and component file is

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="geneoptions" formControlName="gene" appendTo="body"></p-dropdown>
```

But this css is affecting in all other files also. If I removed the `!important` it is not affecting in other pages and this is not working with particular component itself. How to fix this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the panelStyleClass in my component,

```
<p-dropdown [options]="geneoptions" formControlName="gene" appendTo="body" panelStyleClass="overlay-zindex"></p-dropdown>

.overlay-zindex{
   z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="geneoptions" formControlName="gene" appendTo="body" [style]={'z-index':'999 !important'}></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: I tried with this solution also but this is not working because, the ui-dropdown-panel appending to the body not with the specific div

Comment: i have updated. you can see https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown custom content may be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize the z-index with the p-dropdown attribute baseZIndex. This way, you don't need to set it in css, and it affects only the dropdown where the attribute is set.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a single page application framework hence all the CSS would be combined and CSS styles will be created inside style tag of the single html page. If we are having a CSS class with name that is common to other component's elements it does affects it.

In case of component specific CSS, create a custom class name something like,

```
.mycomponent-ui-dropdown-panel {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

and add the class to the element of the component's html where we need this change to be applied. This will make sure that other elements of other components are not affected by the CSS style.

Comment: I tried with this solution but this is not working because, the ui-dropdown-panel appending to the body not with the specific component.